# Split sparse matrix by rows

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` of `(8723, 1741277)` dimensions.

How can I efficiently split it in n chunks by rows?

It is better that the chunks are approximately equal in terms of the number of rows.

I am saying approximately because it depends on whether (number of rows)/(number of chunks) gives back any remainder.

I think that you can easily do this in with `numpy.split` for arrays but it does not seem to work for sparse matrices.

Specifically, I get this error if I choose n-chunks number which is not perfectly divisible with 8723:

```
ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division
```

and I get this error if I choose n-chunks number which is perfectly divisible with 8723:

```
AxisError: axis1: axis 0 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

The reason I want to split the sparse matrix in chunks is because I want to convert my sparse matrix to a (dense) array but I cannot directly do it because it is too big as a whole.

Comment: Do you want the chunks to be sparse matrices or arrays?

Comment: @user3483203, basically the reason I am doing this is because I want to convert my sparse matrix to a (dense) array but I cannot do it because it is too big. This is why I want to split it in chunks. So my final goal is the latter of what you state but I am good with the former too I guess.

Comment: If you look at the code for `np.split` (down one or two layers) you see it just creates a list of slices.  You can do the same with a sparse matrix: [M[0:10,:], M[10:20,:],...]`. You even get to do your own math to figure out the number and size of the slices.

Comment: @hpaulj it is expected that `np.split` does sth like that and I thought of coding the solution to my question by myself. But I also I thought there is already a function which does that but I am not aware of it because I have not worked so much with sparse matrices etc.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit Have you tried `np.array_split` instead of `np.split` ?

Comment: @GeoMSI, yes I get this error: `AxisError: axis1: axis 0 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0`

Comment: @GeoMSI he has stated that the matrix is too large to make dense in his question.

Comment: @user3483203 Oh sorry, my bad:)

Comment: The axis error is the result of `np.split` naively trying to make an dense array out of the sparse one.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [6]: from scipy import sparse                                                                     
In [7]: M = sparse.random(12,3,.1,'csr')                                                             
In [8]: np.split?                                                                                    
In [9]: np.split(M,3)                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     55     try:
---> 56         return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
     57 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    687         else:
--> 688             raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
    689 

AttributeError: swapaxes not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-11a4dcdd89af> in <module>
----> 1 np.split(M,3)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py in split(ary, indices_or_sections, axis)
    848             raise ValueError(
    849                 'array split does not result in an equal division')
--> 850     res = array_split(ary, indices_or_sections, axis)
    851     return res
    852 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py in array_split(ary, indices_or_sections, axis)
    760 
    761     sub_arys = []
--> 762     sary = _nx.swapaxes(ary, axis, 0)
    763     for i in range(Nsections):
    764         st = div_points[i]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in swapaxes(a, axis1, axis2)
    583 
    584     """
--> 585     return _wrapfunc(a, 'swapaxes', axis1, axis2)
    586 
    587 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     64     # a downstream library like 'pandas'.
     65     except (AttributeError, TypeError):
---> 66         return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     67 
     68 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     44     except AttributeError:
     45         wrap = None
---> 46     result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
     47     if wrap:
     48         if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):

AxisError: axis1: axis 0 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

If we apply `np.array` to `M` we get a 0d object array; just a naive wrapper around the sparse object.

```
In [10]: np.array(M)                                                                                 
Out[10]: 
array(<12x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
In [11]: _.shape                                                                                     
Out[11]: ()
```

split a correct dense equivalent:

```
In [12]: np.split(M.A,3)                                                                             
Out[12]: 
[array([[0.        , 0.61858517, 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]]), array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]), array([[0.        , 0.89573059, 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.02334738],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])]
```

and a direct sparse split:

```
In [13]: [M[i:j,:] for i,j in zip([0,4,8],[4,8,12])]                                                 
Out[13]: 
[<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
```

Slicing like this isn't as efficient with sparse matrices as with dense ones.  Dense slices are views.  Sparse ones must be copies.  The only exception is the `lil` format, which has a `get_rowview` method.  While there are many functions for constructing sparse matrices from pieces, there isn't much need for functions that split them up.

It is possible the `sklearn` has some splitting functions.  It has some sparse utility functions that address its own uses of sparse matrices.